# Does a Dictionary<List<_>> qualify as semipersistent?

Tags: c#, f#, prolog

In *[Extended Abstract: A Functional Derivation
of the Warren Abstract Machine](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/wam.pdf)*, Maciej Pir´og and Jeremy Gibbons describe a data structure as 
semi-persistent [7] " if we can backtrack to its previous versions,
but we never simultaneously keep two different modifications (siblings) of
the same ancestor."
Assume some object `dict : System.Collections.Dictionary<A, FSharp.Collections.List<B>>`.
Let the values in the dictionary represent the states relevant to certain keys. Would `dict` be an effectively semi-persistent state-tracking mechanism, assuming only one such `Dictionary` is used? Is that guaranteed by the mutability of the `Dictionary` type coupled with the sequences of previous states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a tough one (to parse, no less answer) - please NOTE: this is per my understanding of the abstract given...
The answer would be Yes AND No.  The key here lies in the usage, not necessarily the structure.  Dictionary itself is persistent.  Like the authors you could use it in a semi-persistent manner.  Having the state values in a list, however, can be a bit troubling, as you may be tempted to retain siblings (again, in the usage).

For a better understanding - go to the source:
https://www.lri.fr/~conchon/publis/spds-esop08.pdf

Comment: That makes sense; I think the real thing I'd need would be some global `List<Map<A,B>>` to capture the historical states. And again, usage would dictate the success therof. Thank you.